# One time only command possible?

Tags: discord.js, bots

I was wondering if its possible to have a command that can be used only once by a user on discord, if so please can someone give me the code for it I would much appreciate it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, SO is not a code-as-a-service platform or whatever. You give code, you tell your problem, and we help you. It's how it works. Here's my answer.

**Of course, yes, it is possible.** Anything that is based on logic can be reproduced by a computer. You just need to learn *how* to think as a computer would. In your case, it'd look like that in pseudo-code.

```
when the command is received:
  has the user already used this command?
    yes:
      return "You've already used this command!"
    no:
      do the work
```

You would need to save the users who already have used the command. For simplicity reasons, the database you would like to use will be represented as an array.

```js
let blockList = []

client.on('message', msg => {
  if (msg.content === "!command") {
    if (blockList.includes(msg.author.id)) return msg.reply("You've already used this command!");
    msg.reply("This is the first time you're using this command! You won't be able to do it again. BUT since the blocklist is stored as an array, the list will be cleared when the program will stop.")
    return blockList.push(msg.author.id)
  }
})
```

Here you have the logic. It's up to you to integrate it into your code, with your database.
I hope I helped, and *please*, do not post another question that looks like that. Try, search, and ask! It'll be much nicer to help you, and I'm sure you would learn much more.